# Recursion: Determine if there are two elements in an array A that sum to k

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, debugging, recursion

I've seen this question asked a lot. I get how it works: we check the sum of the first and the last. If this sum is more than k then last-- or if its less than k then first++. This carries on recursively till either first == last or the sum k is found.
**Note the values in the array are always already sorted in ascending order.

I've tried using recursion, but whenever I run it, it always returns "false". I've tried arrays of all sizes and all test cases return false. e.g. Array[1 2 3 4 5 6], size n = 6 and k = 7 returns false when it should be true.
I cannot seem to find the bug. Can anybody please give me an indication where i am making my mistake? And if I'm not mistaken this runs in O(n) time?

```
public static boolean sum( int[] A, int n, int k ) //where k is the sum needed and n the size of the array
{
     if (k <= A[0] || k >= A[n]*2)
     {
          return false;
     }
     int i = 0;
     int j = n-1;
     return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i, j);
}


private static boolean sum_Recursion(int[] A, int n, int k, int i, int j) 
{
    if(i == j)
    {
         return false;
    } else if((A[i] + A[j]) == k)       
    {
        return true;
    } else if ((A[i] + A[j]) > k)
    {
        return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i, j--);
    }
        return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i++, j);
}
```

Comment: This should be O(n), what is the minimum input which shows a problem? What do you see when you try to debug your code in your debugger? Note: `sum_recursion` doesn't use `n`.  Why does `j = n - 1`? What if the last value is needed?

Comment: @PeterLawrey With any input i.e. I give it an array and then test it it with k values that are the sum of two integers in that array as well as other k's ... in all cases it returns false. It is never true. n is the size of the array (it is given as a parameter. So i make j = n - 1 for the last index.

Comment: If `n` is the size of the array `A[n]` will always throw an Exception.  I suggest you use `A.length` as the size of the array.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes! that was it. I can't believe i didn't notice that. Thank you so much. I changed `(k <= A[0] || k >= A[n]*2)` to `( k <= A[0] || k >= A[n-1]*2)` and now it works. :)

Comment: Note: if A[0] is < 0 the `k <= A[0]` is not a safe check. as -2 + -1 == -3

Comment: I don't know whether the input tested will only be positive, so i guess to be on the safe side I'll take that line out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. the j--, will use j first, then --. it should be j - 1 or --j. Same story with i++.
2. The n parameter seems useless. When do use it, index out bounds.

Fixed version with correct result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println(sum(a, 6, 7)); // ==> true
}

public static boolean sum(int[] A, int n, int k) //where k is the sum needed and n the size of the array
{
    if (k <= A[0] || k >= A[n - 1] * 2) {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = n - 1;
    return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i, j);
}


private static boolean sum_Recursion(int[] A, int n, int k, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return false;
    } else if ((A[i] + A[j]) == k) {
        return true;
    } else if ((A[i] + A[j]) > k) {
        return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i, j - 1);
    }
    return sum_Recursion(A, n, k, i + 1, j);
}
```

Comment: Note: your version will also find  -1 + 2 = 1, the OP's version assumes no values are negative. +1

Comment: Thanks. Oh that makes sense i should have realized that! :| I don't have a choice about the n parameter, we were given the method header and have to complete the code inside using the given parameters. I changed my code regarding the i and j but unfortunately it still returns false. :(

Comment: @user156177 Updated the answer. changed A[n] * 2 to A[n - 1] * 2.

Comment: `n` is not used in `sum_Recursion` and can be removed. `n` could also be replaced with `A.length` in `sum` and removed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The O(n) algorithm:

1. Insert array elements into a hashtable or hashmap
2. Iterate over the array and see `k - currentElement` is present in the hash data structure